# "A collaboration with" or "Collaboration with"

Tags: zero-article

The sentence, at the beginning of a new paragraph, goes:

"A collaboration with Dr. xxx and his colleagues would yyy".

Is it "A collaboration with" or "Collaboration with"? Microsoft Word is unhappy with the article.

Comment: The answers below address the primary question. I'd add that you may want to say "Collaboration **of** X and Y"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Word should not be trusted. *Collaboration* can be either a mass noun ***or*** a count noun, depending on context. So the sentence is correct either with or without the article.

*"A collaboration ..."* would be more appropriate if you are talking about a specific project where you work with Dr. xxx, while *"Collaboration ..."* would be more appropriate if you are talking about working with Dr. xxx in general. But there are lots of situations where both are appropriate, and I suspect your situation is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

If dropping the article sounds strange, you could rephrase, e.g., "A collaborative effort with Dr. xxx and his colleagues would yyy," or, "Collaborating with Dr. xxx and his colleagues would yyy."

I don't, however, know the technical reason for MS Word complaining about the article.

I included the following originally, but it's not relevant if someone else (the author) is also part of the collaboration: As an aside, I would say, "A collaboration **between** Dr. xxx and his colleagues..." (Or, "Dr. xxx's collaboration with his colleagues...")

Comment: What if it is me the one who is supposed to collaborate with Dr. xxx and his colleagues?

Comment: Edited my answer. You have other options in addition to the examples I provided if your style of writing permits the use of personal pronouns, e.g., "I could collaborate with Dr. xxx and his colleagues to yyy," or, "My collaboration with Dr. xxx and his colleagues would yyy."

Comment: Yes, I like the "My collaboration" option. Thanks!

Comment: Although I am still not sure. "A collaboration with Dr. xxx and his colleagues would help me master yyy". It's a job application, I can't say I am already collaborating.

Comment: "Collaborating with Dr. xxx and his colleagues would help me master yyy"?